# Why std::string str = {}?

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw this in some code I try to recompile for VC++ 2013:

```
std::string str;
[...]
str = {}
```

VC++ 2013 complains about that:

```
error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
```

So I am trying to understanding what it specifically does.

**So why use `str = {}` instead of `str = ""`? What are the differences if any?**

Comment: It looks like someone wanted to assign an empty char array to str. But I guess it could be interpreted as, for example, an int array as well.

Comment: So is it safe to change it to str = ""?

Comment: I'd prefer `str.clear()`

Comment: I guess it's safe, but I am not completely sure. Try it, or as Blastfurnace mentioned, try str.clear().

Comment: The code compiles just fine both with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.4 trunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in MSVC. What it means: it assigns empty `initializer_list<char>` to your `str` variable. You can fix this by using explicit creation:`str = std::string{};` it will preserve original meaning and will work with MSVC. I'd recommend to file a bug report to MS connect.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a bug. `basic_string` has several `operator=`, and the overload resolution using a list-initialization is described in [over.ics.list]. As far as I can see, three of the overloads should be ranked as Exact Matches.

Comment: The problem here is *not* the overload resolution between constructors, but the overload resolution between "ordinary" functions. This is different, as we don't just have *one* type to construct from the braced-init-list, but several types. The "conversion sequences" required to construct these types now have to be compared to find the best overload for `operator=`.

Comment: @DyP The code compiles just fine both with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.4 trunk.

Comment: :/ There's yet another tie-breaker that applies here (I should have guessed that..) [over.ics.rank]/3: "List-initialization sequence `L1` is a better conversion sequence than list-initialization sequence `L2` if `L1`
converts to `std::initializer_list<X>` for some `X` and `L2` does not." So even though several of the overloads are ranked as Exact Matches, the `initializer_list` overload is selected unambiguously (or should be..).

Comment: @Dyp, >>This is different, as we don't just have one type to construct from the braced-init-list, but several types<< It's wrong we have only one type and this type is std::string so the reference I've pointed out perfectly describes the situation. We have right hand side assigment([dcl.init.list]/1) and empty brace initialization([dcl.init.list]/3). No other points are relevant here. Overloading has nothing to do with this situation except that MSVC has some bug with it.

Comment: The right side of an assignment refers to the built-in assignment, not an overloaded assignment operator. For an overloaded `=` (i.e. for any class type), the whole expression `str = {}` is transformed to `str.operator=({})`, see [over.match.oper]. Then, we have an "ordinary" function call and overload resolution. (For example, you can write `std::string() = std::string()` even though for built-in assignment, you need a modifiable lvalue at the lhs.)

Comment: @DyP, yes but how it changes anything? Proceed from it to point 3 and you have `if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the
object is value-initialized` How could it be ambiguous? It perfectly match the non-explicit string ctor and we have no job for overload resolution

Comment: The expression `str = {}` is neither an assignment (in the sense of the built-in assignment) nor an initialization. Therefore, list-initialization doesn't apply directly to it. Similarly, you have overload resolution in `void foo(int); void foo(double); foo( {} );`. That the left hand side of `str = {}` is a `string` doesn't care. Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca999a1ad0d5a3d) of how it can go wrong. The selected `std::string::operator=` in the OP's example btw. is **not** the copy-assignment, but `std::string::operator=(std::initializer_list<char>)`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Example was great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = {""}
```

Works well and preserves original meaning of bracket assignment.